# No me inserta en base de datos Sqlite con unity 3d y IOs

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, unity3d

Tengo la siguiente situación: estoy utilizando una base de datos en **`sqlite`** en una aplicación de `unity3d` **(5.6.7f1)** para `iOS` **(12.4)**.

La conexión con la base de datos, se me establece sin problema puedo leer los datos que ya tengo grabado.

El problema se me presenta a la hora de insertar los datos que me envía un error:

**Error del debug del xcode**

> SqliteException: Attempt to write a read-only database
>
> attempt to write a readonly database   at
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Reset (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement stmt)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Step
>   (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement stmt) [0x00000] in :0    at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader..ctor
>   (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior
>   behavior) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   PopulateGrid.insertDb () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[]
>   parameters) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T]
>   (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData
>   eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction1 functor) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchPress
>   (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, Boolean
>   pressed, Boolean released) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchEvents ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () [0x00000] in
>   :0 
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject,
>   BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData,
>   Boolean, Boolean)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()   (Filename:
>   currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Buscando en internet, me encontré que es era un error de permiso.

Entre las cosas que me sugerían que hiciera estaba cambiar la extensión de **.byes** a **.db** y que el directorio donde de guardara la base de datos para la conexión en el caso de **IOs** fuera **RAW**.

A pesar de estos cambios aun me sigue sin insertar registro.

Mi pregunta es: de que forma puedo darle el permiso de lectura y escritura a mi base de datos **`sqlite`** en el dispositivo **`IOs`**.

Gracias.

**Este es el código de llamo a mi conexion.**

```
conn = Application.dataPath + "/Raw/" + namedb;

if(!File.Exists(conn)){
    File.Create (conn);
}
```

Comment: el mensaje de error dice "attempt to write a readonly database", validaste si tienes persimos de escritura en la carpeta o en el archivo donde se encuentra el .db ? la extension no creo que tenga relacion, valida los permisos en la carpeta

Comment: Ya valide los permisos de la carpeta y estaba solo lectura, los cambio desde el fichero  también el directorio pero cuando compilo para el Ipad me sigue diciendo el mismo mensaje. Estos cambios los hice en el proyecto que tengo creado por unity en el directorio que el me crea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace unos días, publiqué esta pregunta y ya hoy finalmente tengo la solución al problema que presentaba. Les explico que es lo que sucede y por si alguien mas le hace falta, en el algún momento.

En el momento de la compilación de **unity3d** para **IOs**, el nombre del director donde se guarda la base de datos se cambia de **StreamingAssets** a **Raw** y es como se refleja en la estructura de directorio del Xcode. Por lo que no lo tiene que crearlo como yo lo hice, ese fue mi error. Cuando unity3d te crea automáticamente el directorio solo lo crea de lectura, por eso aunque se le defina permiso **lectura y escritura** al directorio en el proyecto de Xcode des Finder, no los mantiene en el momento de la compilación por lo que arroja el seguiente error:

> SqliteException: Attempt to write a read-only database

La solución que encontre es pasar la base de datos a un directorio que tu vieses lectura y escritura y en el caso de **IOs** es **Documents**. A  continuación les dejo las cambios que hay que hacer y como mover la base de datos al directorio **Documents** así como es que se establece la ruta de conexión con la misma.

Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

**En la función start (Aquí es donde hacemos el movimiento a la carpeta de Documents)**

```
conn = Application.dataPath + "/Raw/sqlite/" + namedb;
string destino = Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+ namedb;

if(!File.Exists(destino)){
    File.Copy (conn,destino,true);
    File.SetAttributes (destino,FileAttributes.Normal);
}
```

**Ruta para la conexión de la base de datos Sqlite**

```
    conn = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + namedb;
    if(!File.Exists(conn)){
        File.Create (conn);
    }
```

Nota: En el caso de unity3d **persistentDataPath** estable la ruta hasta el directorio de documentos.